# instanceof not working with aspects in Spring

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, instanceof, aspects

I have a Spring Bean obtained from a factory, say,

```
private ObjectFactory<GoodStudent> studentFactory;

public void somemethod() {
    IStudent astudent = studentFactory.getObject();
    System.out.println(astudent instanceof GoodStudent); // prints false.
}
```

Does this happen because of Aspects? Because, I have a method in GoodStudent that is augmented using Aspects(around aspect), like,

```
public class GoodStudent implements IStudent { ...
    @UsesAspect
    public void logStudent() {....}
```

Is this a limitation in Spring or am I missing something?

**Note :** `System.out.println(astudent instanceof IStudent); // prints true`

Comment: Does `GoodStudent` implement `IStudent`?

Comment: @Alex T. yes, it does. logStudent is in-fact a overridden method.

Comment: Ah okay. From the source you've provided all we see is `public class GoodStudent {` which would imply that it doesn't.

Comment: Can we see the implementation of `ObjectFactory.getObject()` when returning a type of `IStudent`?

Comment: it's a spring Interface method. **org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory**

Comment: What does `System.out.println(astudent.getClass())` print? An `ObjectFactory<Foo>` should only produce objects instanceof `Foo`.

Comment: Could you show us your spring set-up, please?

Comment: @zapl - prints com.sun.proxy.$85 !!

Comment: @Michal - I've used javax annotations mostly..the beans file just has `aop:aspectj-autoproxy` and `<context:component-scan>`

Comment: means you have a "jdk dynamic proxy" per http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies  which only works with interfaces, you'll need to configure that is uses CGLib proxies (or properly "program to the interface" and stay with `IStudent` only)

Comment: How do you retrieve the private ObjectFactory<GoodStudent> studentFactory; ?

Comment: The annotations count as spring set-up too! :)

Comment: @zapl, the reason its getting casted back is cause I'm invoking `astudent.equals(Object anthoerStudent)` where another is also got from the **ObjectFactory**.

Comment: @Michal `ObjectFactory<GoodStudent> studentFactory;`  is Autowired...

Comment: @zapl thanks for the heads up..It works now..forced it to use CGLIB instead of JDK dynamic proxy per the Spring docs.